# Aframe - Clone object3D within Entity

Tags: javascript, aframe

Using a-frame, I load in an `obj` model which contains about 114 people meshes using `<a-assets>`. I then want to find a specific mesh within that array which I will then `clone()` many times throughout the scene. Using plain old three.js I am able to do this with minimal effort, but I can't seem to find a way to do this in the `<a-entity>` structure. I have tried `this.el.sceneEl.appendChild()` but that errors out saying `parameter 1 is not a node`; I also tried `this.el.sceneEl.add()`, but that errors out with `Trying to add an element that doesn't have an object3D`. Any thoughts on the best approach to solving this issue?

people.js

```
AFRAME.registerComponent('people', {
    schema: {
        samplePerson: {default: {}}
    },

    init: function () {
        var el = this.el;

        // Listen for when the model is loaded
        el.sceneEl.addEventListener('model-loaded', this.loadPersonModel.bind(this));
    },

    loadPersonModel: function () {

        // Update all meshes from the object3D which is made up with 114 child meshes
        this.el.object3DMap.mesh.children.forEach(function (obj) {
            obj.material.color = new THREE.Color(0xff0000);
            obj.visible = false;
        });

        // Get a sample person for which we will instantiate all over the place
        this.data.samplePerson = this.el.object3D.getObjectByName("people_silhouette73");

        // Clone ten people throughout the scene
        for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            console.log(this.data.samplePerson);
            if (this.data.samplePerson) {
                var clone = this.data.samplePerson.clone();
                clone.visible = true;

                // Randomly position the object
                clone.position.x += Math.random() * 10;
                clone.position.y += 0.01;
                clone.position.z = -300 + Math.random() * 25;

                // Add the object to the scene
                this.el.sceneEl.appendChild(clone);
            }
        }
   }
});
```

index.html

```
<a-scene>
    <a-assets>
        <a-asset-item id="people-obj" src="./assets/obj/silhouette_people_lowpoly_obj.obj"
                  name="testname"></a-asset-item>
    </a-assets>
    <a-entity obj-model="obj: #people-obj;" obj-name="person" people></a-entity>
    </a-entity>
</a-scene>
```

Answer (score 4):

I would approach this in two steps. First, load the model and hide it (or ideally remove it from the scene entirely). Second, have one or more extra entities that extract parts of the object that they need:

```
<a-entity obj-model="obj: #people-obj;" id="group" visible="false"></a-entity>
<a-entity position="0 0 0"
          model-subset="target: #group;
                        name: person1;"></a-entity>
<a-entity position="3 0 0"
          model-subset="target: #group;
                        name: person2;"></a-entity>
<a-entity position="6 0 0"
          model-subset="target: #group;
                        name: person3;"></a-entity>
```

Then defining the `model-subset` component:

```
AFRAME.registerComponent('model-subset', {
  schema: {
    target: {default: '', type: 'selector'},
    name: {default: ''}
  },
  init: function () {
    var el = this.el;
    var data = this.data;
    data.target.addEventListener('model-loaded', function (e) {
      var model = e.detail.model;
      var subset = model.getObjectByName(data.name);
      el.setObject3D('mesh', subset.clone());
    });
  },
  update: function () { /* ... */ },
  remove: function () { /* ... */ }
});
```

Comment: great call on the `model-subset` component...very clean. If I want to clone `n` people, should I set up a new component which grabs the `id` of the `<a-entity>` and clones `n` people? Also, would you recommend in this new component also grabbing the `id` of the `obj-model` and removing it entirely when the entities have all been created?

Comment: Do you know the list of names in advance? You could make a component that creates child entities from a list of names. Your schema might be `{names: {default: []}}` and then `model-subset-creator="names: person1, person2, person3;"`. [Here's an example creating entities in a loop](https://github.com/donmccurdy/aframe-extras/blob/v3.2.5/examples/platforms/index.html#L51-L66). I'd test removing the model — might not matter much.

Comment: This works well: `<a-entity position="0 0 0" model-subset="target: #group;
                        name: people_silhouette73;" id="standing-person"></a-entity>`, but when I try the following inside a component `var standingPerson = document.querySelector('#standing-person'); this.el.appendChild(standingPerson); standingPerson.setAttribute('position', '10 10 10');` it does not append the object to the scene. Any thoughts on how to clone this model-subset `<a-entity>` over and over with random positions?

Comment: Your code looks right. The link in my last comment includes random positions. If this isn't working I think you will need to set up a Codepen or JSFiddle demo.